# Writing to JSON in Python results in duplicating the file contents

Tags: python

I've had this recurring issue where when I write to a JSON in Python it duplicates everything

As Python is not my forte, I'm not really sure what else I can do other than to clear the JSON before writing to it.

Comment: In your own words, what do you think the `"r+"` in your code means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first copy is the original contents of the file; after you do `json.load(output)`, the "current position" is at the end of the file. In order to overwrite the file, you will need to (a) go back to the beginning, and (b) remove the rest of the file, in case the new value is shorter than the old.

```py
output.seek(0)
json.dump(TempList, output, indent=4)
output.truncate()
```

Comment: Why not just load, close, and open for writing?

Comment: Load, close and open for writing would also work; some of the corner cases would be different, but overall it'd be pretty similar.

Comment: In the long run, you will find code that just opens the file twice to be much less painful.

Comment: Both ways are common patterns: opening the file twice is common when we're talking about input/output files (typically separate ones); keeping the file open and passing it around is the pattern used with a database session.